# What is the purpose of the JQuery object promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For a couple of years, I was dealing with a part time problem where some DOM elements loaded with jquery [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function were not accessible immediately after the function call (The behaviour was a bit like executing a function without waiting for the document ready event).  Even though `.html()` is suppose to be synchronous, this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18040133/315493) (and also this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162181/callback-function-for-jquery-html/11163152#11163152)) suggests using the promise of the `html` function:

```
$('#divId').html("<h1>hello</h1>").promise().done(function(){
    //Callback
});
```

A promise could make sense in such context but what intrigues me about this promise is that it will also be returned with every jquery's object:

```
$('#divId').promise().done(function(){
    //Will also be called...
});
```

Since I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation of the `html` function, I was wondering what was the real purpose of this promise and if it is used correctly in this context.

Comment: The promise returned resolves when all current animations on the given collection are complete.

Comment: The linked answer is simply wrong.

Comment: No, just the specific one you linked to, that has 30+ upvotes.

Comment: This [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11163152/315493) is also wrong

Comment: Yes, that one too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two methods are not related. The reason people often suggest this is because someone found out that they could use `.promise().done()` to make their code that has a race condition work. It worked for the same reason wrapping the same code in `setTimeout(fn, 0)` would make it work; it pushes it off to the callback queue to be ran later, likely after the browser performs a render or after some other async callback completes.

`.html` is synchronous, does not have a callback, and does not need a callback. However, the browser's renderer is asynchronous, so it won't render the change until after the callstack is clear. Using .promise pushes the callback off to the callback queue, thus running the code after a render which resolves the race condition or async logic flaw.

`.promise()` used on a jquery collection returns a promise that will resolve once all currently running jquery animations are complete. If there are no currently running animations, the promise will resolve immediately and the callback will be pushed to the callback queue to be called once the stack is clear.

It's nothing more than a bandaid. I'd suggest not using it, and instead fixing whatever async logic flaw is causing it to be the solution.

Comment: So how do one wait for the browser render to complete? I want to add an event listener to the element I just added from the `.html` method. I don't get the asnyc logic flaw part for my case

Comment: document ready, window load, else if you have async crap happening, you have to wait for each one individually. If you need to wait for the renderer to run, use request animation frame or settimeout.