# after appending options to select box, selected is not honored

Tags: jquery, append, html-select, selected

I've seen a lot of other questions about using jQuery to dynamically append options to a select box, and I'm follow their instructions but it's still not selecting the option.  Here's the HTML:

```
<select id="updated-value-dropdown" class="form-control" style="min-width: 10em;">
</select>
```

And here's the Javascript:

```
$('#edit-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  target_element = $(this).find('#updated-value-dropdown');
  target_element.html(''); // clear options
  var add_options = getOptionsToAdd();
  for (var i = 0; i < add_options.length; i++) {
    target_element.append(new Option(add_options[i], add_options[i], i === 0, i === 0));
  }
}
```

The result is a drop-down box with the correct options, and I can see when I inspect the page that the first option is marked as "selected" in the HTML as it should be, but it still isn't show up as being actually selected when the modal is shown...  why isn't this working?

This is what the dropdown looks like on the page (without having clicked it):

[image: Without clicking]

This is what the dropdown looks like when I click on it -- as you can see, the first option is "selected" with a check mark next to it, but as you can see in the image above, it's not actually appearing as the value in the actual box (unless I manually click the value):

[image: With clicking]

Also, I'm using bootstrap, I don't know if that has anything to do with it...

Comment: can you show us all the necessary code.. maybe the problem is when showing it in the modal..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh god I'm an idiot -- there was another place in the code that was calling `target_element.val(...)` and setting it to a value which wasn't one of the options in the options list, so that was clearing the value I was trying to select.

Comment: don't say yourself an idiot, all people (including me) make mistake sometimes :-) glad you found it.

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this (on your last line):

```
target_element
.append(new Option(add_options[i], add_options[i], i === 0, i === 0))
.promise()
.done(function() {
    target_element.find('option:first').prop('selected',true);
    //if you want to select first option after append really done
});
```

sorry if I misunderstand your need, but I show you the way.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I just tried this, but it had the same results as before.

Comment: What is .promise for in this case? what do you think you are waiting on? I don't see any animations.

Comment: @KevinB don't be wrong, `.promise()` is not only for animation, it's for ajax and even DOM insertion like `.append()`, `.html()`, they are rarely (or even sometime) risky without `.promise()`. you should read more about it.

Comment: Sorry, but you are incorrect. I explained this in more detail over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45085940/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-jquery-object-promise/45086288#45086288 Refer to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) if you don't believe me.

Comment: This is a very common misconception that has been re-posted ad nauseum on SO answers, blogs, and tutorials all over the net.

Comment: @KevinB I see :o thank you for your nice information, maybe I've wrong because I was read & rely on this article https://digitizor.com/jquery-html-callback-function-using-promise/ ... but then I have question, for example `$('div').append('<p></p>').find('p:last').text('hello')` (imagine if `append` and `find` is not that simple), is it no problem? am I just too afraid (?)

Comment: Interacting with the DOM is always a synchronous action, so there's no chance you could ever do something in a single chain that would warrant needing to wait. You would only need to wait if you were doing *other* actions that are asynchronous, such as a jquery animation or an ajax request.

Comment: @KevinB thank you very much for the correction, friend. glad to meet you here, if not, I'll keep implement that "common misconception" on the future. :-)